# In Emacs on Windows, how can I make Emacs ignore the Windows key completely?

Tags: windows, emacs

Is there a way I can make emacs completely ignore the Windows key under all circumstances?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you press that makes this a problem? I've never had issues with emacs doing funny stuff with the Windows key.

Comment: I have mapped Win+(other keys) combos to things in Windows itself.

Comment: If you've mapped win+key combos to other things then they are executed before emacs can get them, aren't they? How emacs can cause a problem?

Comment: Because in order to make a combo, I have to press the Win key _first_, thus causing Emacs to complain about me pressing the Win key.

Comment: So let's say the emacs window has focus and you press the Windows key. What happens for you? For me, the Start Menu pops up; emacs doesn't seem to intercept the keypress or anything.

Comment: If I merely press the Win key and nothing else, the start menu pops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you press `C-h k` and then the windows key you should see what key is being executed.  Then you can bind that key to `ignore`.  For example below is how to set `f1` to be ignored.

```
(global-set-key [f1] 'ignore)
```

Answer (score 0):

I always remap my caps lock to be control using a registry hack. (vim user)

There are nicer toys for this sort of thing like this:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/

We'll call this part of the vim/emacs truce...

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. A Windows user probably doesn't want to remap the Windows key across the board.

Comment: I'm a windows user. I would remap the windows key to something else in that case, and the windows key to something I would want. It's really up to the user. I've done it before to avoid whacking the windows key.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what tool you use to bind your Win+ mappings, but I use [Authotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) which probably can also be used to disable the win key for emacs ony.

For example, here's a script which may work to disable the left win key for emacs (untested):

```
#IfWinactive, ahk_class Emacs
LWin::
  return
#IfWinactive
```